# Neo4J/Cypher Filter nodes based on multiple relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4J and Cypher:

Given the diagram below, I want to be able to start at node 'A' and get all the children that have a 'ChildOf' relationship with 'A', but not an 'InactiveChildOf' relationship. So, in this example, I would get back A, C and G. Also, a node can get a new parent ('H' in the diagram) and if I ask for the children of 'H', I should get B, D and E.

I have tried

`match (p:Item{name:'A'}) -[:ChildOf*]-(c:Item) where NOT (p)-[:InactiveChildOf]-(c) return p,c`

however, that also returns D and E.

Also tried:

`match (p:Item{name:'A'}) -[rels*]-(c:Item) where None (r in rels where type(r) = 'InactiveChildOf') return p,c`

But that returns all.

Hopefully, this is easy for Neo4J and I am just missing something obvious. Appreciate the help!

[image: Parent/Child diagram]

Example data: `MERGE (a:Item {name:'A'}) MERGE (b:Item {name:'B'}) MERGE (c:Item {name:'C'}) MERGE (d:Item {name:'D'}) MERGE (e:Item {name:'E'}) MERGE (f:Item {name:'F'}) MERGE (g:Item {name:'G'}) MERGE (h:Item {name:'H'}) MERGE (b)-[:ChildOf]->(a) MERGE (b)- [:InactiveChildOf] ->(a) MERGE (c)-[:ChildOf]->(a) MERGE (d)-[:ChildOf]->(b) MERGE (e)-[:ChildOf]->(b) MERGE (f)-[:ChildOf]->(c) MERGE (f)- [:InactiveChildOf] ->(c) MERGE (g)-[:ChildOf]->(c) MERGE (b)-[:ChildOf]->(h)`

*Note, I understand that I could simply put an "isActive" property on the ChildOf relationship or remove the relationship, but I am exploring options and trying to understand if this concept would work.*

Comment: It would be much simpler (as a data model and in coding) and more efficient (in time and storage) to simply put an `isActive` property on the ChildOf relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a query interpreted as: find all the nodes, the path to which passes through the nodes unrelated by `InactiveChildOf` to the previous node, the request might be something like this:

```
match path = (p:Item{name:'A'})<-[:ChildOf*]-(c:Item)
with nodes(path) as nds
unwind range(0,size(nds)-2) as i
with nds, 
     nds[i] as i1, 
     nds[i+1] as i2 
     where not (i1)-[:InactiveChildOf]-(i2)
with nds, 
     count(i1) as test 
     where test = size(nds)-1
return head(nds), 
       last(nds)
```

**Update**: I think that this version is better (check that between two nodes there is no path that will contain at least one non-active type of relationship):

```
match path = (p:Item {name:'A'})<-[:ChildOf|InactiveChildOf*]-(c)
with p, c, 
     collect( filter( r in rels(path) 
                      where type(r) = 'InactiveChildOf'
              ) 
     ) as test
          where all( t in test where size(t) = 0 )
return p, c
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your solution works for both the original and updated constraints. However, I am concerned about performance as it profiles to 75 db hits to get 3 items. I will play around with it to see if I can improve.

Comment: @stdob-- you may want to take a look at the APOC Procedure pairsMin(), which takes in a collection and returns a list of list pairs (so [1, 2, 3, 4] becomes [[1,2], [2,3], [3, 4]]), allowing you to more clearly compare each adjacent node pair for the relationship to exclude. Unsure how it compares performance-wise, but worth a look.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thank you - this is a useful procedure. But, when I try to use it get the error:  `Type mismatch: expected Node or Relationship but was Any`.

Comment: @stdob-- Sounds like a bug in the procedure, I saw something similar when attempting to use their pairs() function for a similar case. I think they implemented it correctly when introduced, but maybe something snuck in. Is this with the latest version? If so, it's worth filing a bug for this.

Comment: @stdob--Thanks! This works great. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

By reading and examining the graph, correct me if I'm wrong but the actual text representation of the cypher query should be

> Find me nodes in a path to A, all nodes in that path cannot have an outgoing
>   InactiveChildOf relationship.

So, in Cypher it would be :

```
MATCH p=(i:Item {name:"A"})<-[:ChildOf*]-(x)
WHERE NONE( x IN nodes(p) WHERE (x)-[:InactiveChildOf]->() )
UNWIND nodes(p) AS n
RETURN distinct n
```

Which returns

[image]

Comment: Edited the query to avoid to return duplicated nodes if they are in more than one path

Comment: This does not seem sufficient to answer the question. The returned nodes must also be on a path to `A` consisting of `ChildOf` relationships.

Comment: Good catch, the type of the rel in the match should be set. Leaving that up to you guys, on mobile and off :)

Comment: I added the rel type (and removed the binding since it's not used) but I'm falling azzzzzzlkdsjg on my keyboard so pls sanity check
Also thanks @ChristopheWillemsen for writing idiomatic Cypher, it's so much easier to read

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Thanks for the response! It works great for 'A' but I updated the question to add an additional constraint. Child 'B' could get a new parent 'H'. Yours works for 'A', but not for 'H'. Your solution profiles much better with only 24 db hits. I will see if I can update to work with new constraint.